# I can't call a variable declared in the methods class

Tags: c#

I'm not super experienced in programming so I'm picking up where I left off by practicing a text based game. The issue I'm having is right at the start I can't call on a variable declared in the class under a method inside of it.

My code looks like this

```
    class Program
    {
        string PlayerName;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GameTitle();
        }
        static void GameTitle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.WriteLine("Whats your name?");
            PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + PlayerName + " to your new game!");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get the PlayerName to print onto the console but it doesn't recognize it. I know declaring the variable inside the method would work but I intend to call on it in multiple methods how can I do that?

Comment: make it `static string PlayerName;`

Comment: The method is `static` your var is not. Neither of them should be.

Comment: You cannot access `non static` property, method inside static items

Answer (score 0):

Both your **Method** and your **Variable** should be **Static**

Therefore to fix this problem all you need to do is write `static string name;`
instead of `string name;`

I recommend checking out [This](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static) to learn more about Static in C#.

Comment: I'd actually recommend the opposite: Neither of them should be static. Either way fixes the problem but the non-static route will lead to less refactoring later on.